# npm ERR! code EBADENGINE - this error out of nowhere on my sveletkit project

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, appwrite

So there is a web project that I started some months ago with Sveltekit. I shelved it for a bit and today I needed to try and connect the svelte app to an appwrite backend. As I am trying to install the appwrite SDK, I get this error. Please help!

error:
**

> PS C:\Users\nqo\Desktop\Dzimbanhete Project\dzimbanhete-app> npm
> install appwrite npm ERR! code EBADENGINE npm ERR! engine Unsupported
> engine npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm:
> dzimbanhete-app@0.0.1 npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version
> of node/npm: dzimbanhete-app@0.0.1 npm ERR! notsup Required:
> {"node":"^16.x"} npm ERR! notsup Actual:
> {"npm":"8.19.2","node":"v18.12.1"} npm ERR! A complete log of this run
> can be found in:

**
[image]
NB: I had tried some demo deployments and they worked well before this on digital ocean.

Comment: Can you provide the full `package.json`?

Comment: i'm facing this same issue out of nowhere. i don't know why it's happening. i tried changing node versions but to no avail